# symfony2 fails with error "This value should not be null"

Tags: symfony, assert

I'm working with a symfony2 form and now I get the message "This value should not be null."..
Now "THIS VALUE".. what is this value? and how to figure it out?

By dumping the errors: ($form->getErrors()) I get

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[2418]
      protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'This value should not be null.' (length=30)
      protected 'messageParameters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'messagePluralization' => null
  1 => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[2420]
      protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'This value should not be null.' (length=30)
      protected 'messageParameters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'messagePluralization' => null
  2 => 
    object(Symfony\Component\Form\FormError)[2421]
      protected 'messageTemplate' => string 'This value should not be null.' (length=30)
      protected 'messageParameters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'messagePluralization' => null
```

After toggeling some asserts one formError was gone. That what by:

```
 /**
  * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
  * @Assert\NotNull()
  */
 protected $price;

var_dump( $reservation->getPrice(), is_null( $reservation->getPrice() ) );
```

Result:

```
float 733

boolean false
```

But in the asserts is this a error..

Failures on entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $price;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Caravan", inversedBy="caravan")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="caravan_id", referencedColumnName="id")
* @Assert\NotNull()
*/
protected $caravan;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $created;
```

Those are the 3 properties that I set in the controller BEFORE the isValid check.. If I do:

```
$form->getData();
```

It has the right data.

Comment: Please provide a dump of the form and any associated filters as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was:

Will not work:

```
$form->bind( $request );

$reservation->setCreated( new \DateTime() );

if( $form->isValid() ){

}
```

Will work:

```
$reservation->setCreated( new \DateTime() );

$form->bind( $request );

if( $form->isValid() ){

}
```

When the form binds he will check the of hes valid or not.
So after that he will not check it again.

So a little advice, bind it at the last moment before the isValid check =)